# laravel save create the object but not insert in database

Tags: php, laravel

I have problems in keeping the data in the database, the query creates the object for me returns the id of the same, but not the row inserted in the table.

This is the way in which I keep the data:

```
  $lineup = new lineup(); <br>
  $lineup->user_id = Auth::user()->id;<br>
  $lineup->date = $fecha; <br>
  $lineup->salary_rest = $salary_rest;<br>

   $lineup->save();
```

PD: I am using laravel 4.2.

Comment: What database are you using? If you look in your config/database.php file it should have 'default' => "something here"

Comment: I am working with mysql, but the rare is that in other seccion the save() works fine.

Comment: Is any of your code calling DB::beginTransaction() ? and never commiting it? DB::commit()?

Comment: It is not just this section, change the way of doing the insert but not serves me.

Comment: Brett thank you very much, I did well review the code and me di account the commit() was commented.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 things to check when items aren't saving to the database.

Check the config/database.php file to ensure it's using the correct database driver.

Secondly ensure if a Transaction is being used that a commit statement is called.

```
DB::beginTransaction()
// Your code
DB::commit()
```

Without the commit the changes won't flow through to the database